# Undefined reference to class, despite making it public and implementing

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, undefined-reference

I have a small project composed of a main file (`main.cpp`) in which I have just added a new function, and a class pojemnik defined in a header (pojemnik.h) with a source file (`pojemnik.cpp`) compiled separately.

I use a makefile.  Here an extract:

```
program: obj obj/main.o obj/pojemnik.o
    g++ obj/main.o -o program

obj/main.o: src/main.cpp inc/pojemnik.h
    g++ ${CXXFLAGS} -c src/main.cpp -o obj/main.o

obj/pojemnik.o: src/pojemnik.cpp inc/pojemnik.h
    g++ ${CXXFLAGS} -c src/pojemnik.cpp -o obj/pojemnik.o
```

Here's my link to the [GitHub](https://github.com/218478/PAMSI/tree/test/lab_29.02_odnowa/prj), where all my code is available, in case the elements above are not sufficient.

When I try to compile it, I'm getting following errors:

```
obj/main.o: In function `zapiszDoPojemnika(unsigned int)
undefined reference to `pojemnik::pojemnik(int)
undefined reference to `pojemnik::zapisz(int)
undefined reference to `pojemnik::zwroc_rozmiar()
undefined reference to `pojemnik::~pojemnik()
undefined reference to `pojemnik::~pojemnik()
```

I've implemented the method for all the functions. Everything was compiling properly until I have created that function. Can you point at the error I made ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from your makefile:

```
program: obj obj/main.o obj/pojemnik.o
    g++ obj/main.o -o program
```

You have forgotten `obj/pojemnik.o` in the command, so that g++ will try to link without. THis is why it doesn't find any symbol of the pojemnik class.

Comment: Thank you. That  always is a simple thing. I'll upload the code tomorrow when I come back.